# where can i download archives of eclipse,ibm jazz and mozilla

Tags: data-request, releasing-data, machine-learning, nlp, research

Where can i find and download bug reports, mailing list archives,execution logs,test cases,for the following projects?
1.Eclipse
2.Ibm jazz and
3.Mozilla

Comment: Please try to do at least a little work for yourself.  A search for 'eclipse bug reports' immediately found https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/ .  But most of these are *not* open data.  Especially not mailing list archives, where the author of each post maintains a copyright.  I would suspect that the same would be true for trouble tickets unless the submitter explicitly gives up their rights in the.

Comment: @Joe my question is clear, i want to download bug reports and not just view them."bugs.eclipse.org/bugs" is known universal and i dont need your help to hit that link.

Comment: My complaint about it not being clear is your other question about 'all project' (which I suspect may have been 'all projects').  My complaint about this question is that it seems your question is answerable with a simple internet search ... if that doesn't solve your problem, you need to explain why.

Comment: @joe i am requesting for data sets that are available open.

Comment: @joe a simple search pointed me only to the archives of these projects. but i wasnt able to hit an open data set for me to work with. i hope i am clear now, i need an "open data set" and i dont want to access copyright protected archives(which a simple google search points to).

Comment: It's quite probably that such a thing doesn't exist.  Status (open/fixed/won't fix) and such might be exempt from copyright, but as someone has to make a decision about the 'won't fix' cases, it's possible that it could be challenged.  I doubt any trouble ticket system data would be available as 'open data'.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/35304/discussion-between-hemaa-mathavan-and-joe).